# How to get a async function inside an async function without getting Uncaught (in promise) error

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, ecmascript-6, promise

In my login.js file that has a async login function and I am trying to get IP address of the user using another async function in helper.js file.

**login.js**

```
    login: async ({ dispatch, commit }, firebaseAuthUser) => { 
    const usersDb = new UsersDB(firebaseAuthUser.uid)
    const userFromFirebase = await usersDb.read(firebaseAuthUser.uid)
    let user = null
    let ip = null

    if (!isNil(userFromFirebase)) {
      const increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)

      setTimeout(() => {
        getUserIPAddress().then((d) => {
          ip = d
          console.log(ip)
        })
      }, '3000')

      console.log(ip)
      usersDb.update({
        id: firebaseAuthUser.uid,
        loginCount: increment,
        lastLoginTimestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        lastKnownIpAddress: ip,
      })
      user = userFromFirebase
    } else {
      user = await createNewUserFromFirebaseAuthUser(firebaseAuthUser)
    }
```

**helper.js**

```
 export async function getUserIPAddress() {
  const fetchRes = fetch('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json')
  fetchRes
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((d) => {
      console.log(d.ip)
      return String(d.ip)
    })
}
```

Console.log is below:

Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field lastKnownIpAddress in document users/KIucHorN8LMvfLcEDB0uo9VqOEB2)

and then the browser spits up the console.log in helper.js file.

I am trying to call a async fetch function inside another async function and I cannot seem to make them wait causing in error.

I tried chaining with .then() in login file, that didn't work.
I tried to remove all async and await key words and run it as regular function, that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async function getUserIPAddress` doesn't return any value and it is `async` for no reason since you never `await` in it.

Also, you wrap the call to that function in a `setTimeout` which means, even if it DID return a value, variable `ip` would still be undefined

try changing the code as follows:

```
login: async ({dispatch, commit}, firebaseAuthUser) => {
    const usersDb = new UsersDB(firebaseAuthUser.uid);
    const userFromFirebase = await usersDb.read(firebaseAuthUser.uid);
    let user = null;
    let ip = null;

    if (!isNil(userFromFirebase)) {
        const increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
        // do you REALLY need to wait 3 seconds here, 
        // or was your setTimeout due to not understanding asynchrony?
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
        ip = await getUserIPAddress();
        console.log(ip);
        usersDb.update({
            id: firebaseAuthUser.uid,
            loginCount: increment,
            lastLoginTimestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            lastKnownIpAddress: ip,
        });
        user = userFromFirebase;
    } else {
        user = await createNewUserFromFirebaseAuthUser(firebaseAuthUser);
    }
```

and

```
export async function getUserIPAddress() {
    const res = await fetch('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json');
    const d = await res.json();
    console.log(d.ip)
    return String(d.ip)
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jaromanda-X, it works as expected. The 3sec delay was something I was just playing with to figure out if fetch was causing the unexpected results.  Thanks for providing the answer and also explaining what I was doing wrong. Appreciate it!